# Get attribute value defined in route in React router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

How can I get the value of attribute defined in route?

```
export default () => (
    <Router>
        <App>           
            <Route exact path="/" title="Home" componenet={Home} />                 
            <Route exact path="/about" title="About" component={About} />
        </App>
      </Router>
);
```

I would like to get the title in app.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {       
        console.log(this.props.title);
    }
}
```

However, it returned undefined.

Comment: Added example in answer, but what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `title` prop to the `Route` component, not the `App` Component. If you need `title` in `App`, you will need to pass it explicitly:

```
export default () => (
    <Router>
        <App title="Home">           
            <Route exact path="/" title="Home" componenet={Home} />                 
        </App>
      </Router>
);
```

However this is likely not what are you trying to achieve as there are multiple `titles` contained inside your `app`.

Comment: May I know how can I do it explicitly?

Comment: Yes, would wanna the title in App displayed differently according to the route rendered

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md

Comment: Nope. Is that more suitable for route path?